# Adjusting edges around markers in legends in GeoPandas plot

Tags: geopandas, legend, matplotlib

I am trying to adjust the edges around the markers in my legend.
Currently my code looks like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,10))
lri_map.plot(column= '30', 
           ax= ax, 
            alpha=1, 
           scheme = 'NaturalBreaks', 
             cmap = 'Reds', 
             edgecolor = 'black',
            linewidth = 0.5, 

           missing_kwds = {
               'color' : 'lightgrey',
               'hatch': '////' ,
               'label' : 'Missing Values'

           }, 

           legend=True,
           legend_kwds={'loc': (0.05, 0.2), 'fontsize' : 10, 'facecolor' : 'white', 'edgecolor': 'white' },
     
           )


ax.set_axis_off()
```

Where `lrimap` is a GeoDataFrame.
I produce the following graph:
[image: output produced my code]

I would love to have an edge (line) around the markers in the legend, [however it seems that by default this is turned off.](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/0f2ca1a802ad6814f5185b45288961b66f51a054/geopandas/plotting.py#L609) Is there any way to add a small black line around the markers (it becomes otherwise hard to see the light red marker)? Somehow it does work for the missing data marker...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for being slow here, just came across this! Try:

```
for legend_handle in ax.get_legend().legendHandles:  
    legend_handle._legmarker.set_markeredgewidth(1)
    legend_handle._legmarker.set_markeredgecolor('k')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the API might have changed recently, but the `legend_handle` object does not have an attribute `_legmarker` anymore.
I instead used the `set_edgecolor()` method:

```
for legend_handle in ax.get_legend().legendHandles:
    legend_handle.set_edgecolor('black')
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this through Google and the other answers gave me a good starting point. Unfortunately, the API changed again with `matplotlib` 3.7 thus the code is now:

```py
for legend_handle in ax.get_legend().legend_handles:
    legend_handle.set_markeredgewidth(1)
    legend_handle.set_markeredgecolor("black")
```

Cheers!

(Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to comment in the GIS stackexchange)